# Automatically fill Form Values from excel spreadsheet html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a large form in html with approximately 100 -150 fields. I was wondering if it was possible to do something like drag and drop / copy and paste text or a spread sheet into the html page so that it automatically populates all the forms fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous ways to automate form filling with C#. The best of these solutions being [Selenium Web Driver](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).

Accessing values from Excel can be done easily using any number of libraries out there as well. I really like [LinqToExcel](http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/), but that might be overkill for what you are doing.

That being said **the real issue is that you need an intelligent way to map values from your spreadsheet to fields in the web page**. That is going to be the sticky bit.